# How Do I start a Terminal in Mac OS from Java

Tags: java, macos

How do I start a terminal from Mac OS from a java program?

The code that I have tried are

```
String[] arg = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "Terminal"};
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(arg).start();

OutputStream out = null;
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("Terminal").start();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c Terminal");
out = proc.getOutputStream();
out.write("cd /home/me/Desktop/".getBytes());
out.flush();
```

However both of em didnt work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works for me just give the absolute path of your terminal app and it should work fine.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal");
```